# Carrying a wide item inside a narrow column

Tags: css

I have a form of width `450px` with one item that has to take the full page's width (990px).

`position:absolute` is a problem because this wide item needs to fit in the flow of elements inside the form. `margin-left:-270px` seems a bit hackish and likely to break down with future rule changes. Is there a better solution?

How can I get an element in the form's flow that takes up the whole page's width?

Comment: Do you have an example? I can't visualize this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using fixed width layouts, I don't really see a margin-left of -270 as being hackish.  If you hadn't posted it yourself, it would be the answer I would suggest.

To make it seem less hackish, an alternative might be to use Less - it's effectively a CSS based language that compiles to plain CSS.  You could then specify the rule so that changes to the form or page width will automatically sort out your margin also:

```
@page_width: 990px;
@form_width: 450px;
...
.full_width_form_element {
  margin-left: (@form_width - @page_width) / 2;
}
```

http://lesscss.org/

Comment: I'm looking into Less. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `overflow` property of CSS. `overflow: auto` to cause scrolling, `overflow: visible` to allow it to leak out of the box. `overflow: hidden` to hide whatever part of it leaks outside the box.

Comment: It's `overflow:visible`, not `overflow:show`. But otherwise, you're correct.

Comment: bahhh you're correct of course. overflow: show did seem odd looking for me. Thanks for the correction :)